# Will it be back compatible to change nullable type to non-nullable?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

For example, if I change the following data type `bool?`

```
[ProtoMember(10)]
public bool? HasEmail { get; set; }
```

to `bool`. Will it be a breakchange?

```
[ProtoMember(10)]
public bool HasEmail { get; set; }
```

The the logic to write `HasEmail` has been changed with `...?? false` so it will never be null in the future.

The data will be stored in Redis. And some other program may try to read it using type `bool?` or `bool`.

Comment: As long as you have nulls in your data, it's a breaking change indeed. If something else writes a null (or a null is already there), then your new code will blow up. But if this code is the only writer, and the other apps just read, then you're good: they're expecting a maybe-null value that just never will be null.

Comment: This code is the only writer. It has updated code for assigning `HasEmail` with `...?? false`. I'm not sure if the existing data in Redis contains null. Maybe I shouldn't change `bool?` to `bool` on readers yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will be fine in the forwards direction; any previously missing data will now report as `false` via omission. However: you should note that if you serialize data from the new code, `false` values will be omitted, so will report as `null` (not `false`) if deserialized via any systems still using the old version.